# How to access child tag's attributes with event handler in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to access the img tag's src attribute. By using `e.target`, it gives me the entire tag set, but I thought I could access by doing `e.target.img.src`, but it didn't work. How can I do that?

```
handleClickOpen(e) {
  console.log(e.target);
}


<Button onClick={this.handleClickOpen}>
  <img src={image.image} alt="product" />
</Buttonz>
```

Comment: Just `e.target.src` should do it.

Comment: Chris you may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the value of the `src` property AND the handler for the synthetic event, you can use a lambda function and pass it as a second parameter, like this:

```
handleClickOpen(event, imageSrc) {
    console.log(imageSrc);
}

<Button onClick={ event => this.handleClickOpen(event, image.image) }>
    <img src={image.image} alt="product" />
</Button>
```

Consider that this is just a fast solution, it isn't the very best practice, inline lambdas aren't properly adviced and everything.

Answer (score 0):

You should be aveare of how event is working.
`e.target` is the deepest element user is clicking on. Consider example bellow.

```
<button onClick={(e) => {console.log(e.target)}} style={{padding: '20px',}}>
    <img src={'someUrl'} alt="product" />
</button>
```

If user clicks directly on image `e.target === <img src="someUrl" alt="product">`. If user clicks on padding of the button `e.target === <button style="padding: 20px;">`

I would recommend to use [react ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) here. So you can save ref to your image and call it when you need.